# Giving Team Admin role on iTunes Connect for outsource firm

Tags: app-store-connect

I need to give Team Admin role for an outsource firm because they'll send applications to iTunes Connect but I'm worry after saw this "Team Privileges" table on Apple Developer Documentation [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH16-SW14):

[image: Team Privileges table developer apple itunes-connect]

Hmmm, Team Admin can "Register, configure, and delete App IDs"... I give them Team Admin Role and call them by phone, and they say "now we can remove App Id, delete button here and I'm able to use it..."

No, They shouldn't be able to do that! Am I doing something wrong?

**Role descriptions:**

**Team agent:**
A team agent is legally responsible for the team and acts as the initial primary contact with Apple. The team agent can invite team members and change the access level of any other team member. There’s only one team agent.

**Team admin:**
A team admin can set the privilege levels of other team members, except the team agent. Team admins manage all assets used to sign your apps, either during development or when your team is ready to distribute an app. Team admins can edit the App ID to enable app services and create technology specific identifiers used throughout the system. Team admins can sign apps for distribution on nondevelopment devices.

**Team member:**
A team member can create their development certificate, register a device connected to their Mac, and create a team provisioning profile using Xcode. Team members can’t register devices and create development provisioning profiles using their developer account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer under "Maintaining Identifiers, Devices, and Profiles" [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html).

**Deleting App IDs**

You can also remove App IDs when you no longer need them. **However, you cannot delete an explicit App ID for an app you uploaded to iTunes Connect**.

Anyway, weird to see that delete button there.